# Multi Threading in Web Service to speed up processing speed

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I do have a business logic processing in desktop program.

However, the data processing is terrible slow when i process with big data, ( I am using MS SQL database). As so , i do a work around. I open a web service project, and package my business logic process into a dll name consoleAttn(), then separate the processing into few Threading, with DotNet Task.Parallel techonology as the code below:

`

```
    DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable("Employee");

    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn.Open();
    }

    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sEmpQuery, cn))
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("Command Text:{0}", sEmpQuery));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Period", sPeriod);
        dtEmp.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }

    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cn.Close();
    }

    Int32 iThread;
    iThread = iNoThread;

    Int32 iCountTable;
    iCountTable = dtEmp.Rows.Count;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total Rows:{0}", iCountTable));

    Int32 IProcNum;
    IProcNum = iCountTable / iThread;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Transaction no:{0}", IProcNum));


    if (iCountTable < iThread)
    {
        Boolean bl;

        AutoHRPay.frmClosePeriod aPay= new AutoHRPay.frmClosePeriod();

        MiscResource AMisc = new MiscResource();
        MiscResource misc = new MiscResource();

        misc.SetDBConn(strCN);


    }
    else
    {
        Boolean[] bl = new Boolean[iThread];

        object locker = new object();

        Parallel.For(1, iThread + 1, i =>
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder strSQL = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            strSQL.Append("(");

            DataTable dtEmpThread = dtEmp.Clone();
            dtEmpThread.Clear();

            for (Int32 j = ((i - 1) * IProcNum + 1); j <= ((i != iThread) ? (IProcNum * i) : iCountTable); j++)
            {
                dtEmpThread.ImportRow(dtEmp.Rows[j-1]);
            }



            int row_counter = 0;

            lock (locker)
            {
                row_counter++;
                streamwriter.WriteLine("Processing row: {0}", row_counter);
            }


            ConsoleAttn aPay = new ConsoleAttn();

            aPay.runConsole();

        });


    }
    streamwriter.Close();
    return "Completed.";
```

1) Do you have any idea, how should i do the asynchronous process when i need to stop process or when the client which called to the web service being collapse ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches that may help, especially if you are talking about bit amount of data to process

- Do not load everything from SQL server at once in huge DataTable
- Do not clone DataTable

First, if dataset is really big, it will take time to transfer this data from SQL server to your computer. Then, a lot of memory is required for this dataset to store while processing. With multiple threads you are effectively doing copies of your whole big dataset. High memory usage can cause to unnecessary garbage collection and worse application performance, especially if server doesn't have much memory. There is a risk of swapping and your performance will be destroyed.

If data rows processing order doesn't matter and every row can be processed independantly from others, you can go this way:

- Read data with DataReader record by record
- Store this data in some thread safe collection
- While you are reading data you can start processing by multiple threads

Probably you will want to use LinkedList collection for its O(1) complexity to add and remove items. Don't forget about thread safety access to this collection.
In this case, what benefits you get:

- Start processing as soon as first bytes from SQL server received
- Less memory usage during processing. You don't need to store some data multiple times, don't need to store data that is already processed, while you are waiting for other data to be processed.

Depending on typical size of data, SQL server config, your server memory amount etc you may want either to load all data from SQL as soon as possible or load data with some delays to make sure there is no much unprocessed records in your collection.